# What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, pagination

What is the best way (performance wise) to paginate results in SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2012 if you also want to get the total number of results (before paginating)?

Comment: I was going to leave this topic alone, because I figured a billion people were going to jump on it, but it wasn't as busy a thread as I thought it would be. There are some articles on using row number and the BETWEEN statement to efficiently do pagination. [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/row_number.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/row_number.aspx)
[http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Pagination_In_SQL_Server_2005.aspx](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Pagination_In_SQL_Server_2005.aspx) and to kind of fake row numbers in sql server 2000 this link should give you somethin

Comment: I've always wondered why they didn't just support specifying an offset as part of TOP (like MySQL/Posgresql support with LIMIT/OFFSET). Eg, they could just have the syntax  "SELECT TOP x,y ...." where x = number of rows, y = starting offset. It would also be backwards compatible.

Comment: hey, me too... sql's 2005 pagination implementation it's really so akward...

Comment: @gregmac - Sql Server 2012 does have limit/offset now.

Comment: The accepted solution does not show how it is the best way (performance wise).  Any data backing it up on large data sets?

Comment: @O.O: A good benchmark can be found here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml. However, the [seek method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609938/521799) will outperform any offset-based pagination.

Comment: this example work me. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9328808/revisions

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging/13991192#13991192)

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Getting the total number of results and paginating are two different operations. For the sake of this example, let's assume that the query you're dealing with is

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '1980-01-01' ORDER BY OrderDate
```

In this case, you would determine the total number of results using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
```

...which may seem inefficient, but is actually pretty performant, assuming all indexes etc. are properly set up.

Next, to get actual results back in a paged fashion, the following query would be most efficient:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      Orders
          WHERE     OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum < 20
ORDER BY RowNum
```

This will return rows 1-19 of the original query. The cool thing here, especially for web apps, is that you don't have to keep any state, except the row numbers to be returned.

Comment: Just to note that ROW_NUMBER() does not exist in SQL Server 2000

Comment: does this return all rows from the inner query & then filter based on outer query? for ex: inner query returns 100,000 & outer query returns only 20.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: think of it as the subquery (inner query) returning a stream, which is then read until the outer WHERE clause is satisfied. How may rows are involved with that, depends entirely on the query, but the optimizer generally does a very good job on minimizing that number. Using the graphical execution plan viewer in SQL Server Management Studio (use Query/Include Actual Execution Plan) is very educational in that regard.

Comment: i am fine with this approach as long as it's not costing too much in terms of process.

Comment: ok, what if you get dublicated in inner select (like when you have inner join) how do you use distinct because RowNumber is different and it does not work

Comment: please check out this link -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging)

Comment: @mdb - I see no proof that this is the best performance wise.  All I see is one way of doing it.  I've read that using TOP is actually more performant.

Comment: @mdb Is there any performance issue with the above query if we have more records ? please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118532/pagination-in-sql-performance-issue

Comment: Microsoft added a new feature to SQL 2012 that makes pagination similar to MySQL. Follow this link to learn how. It's an interesting article: http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch

Comment: This approach does not provide good performance (at least less than 1 second), if table contains lots of records i.e. > 3.000.000 and we are executing query which has "offset / rownum" near 3.000.000. I just tried with a simple table 'person (email PK, firstname, lastname)' containing 3.000.000 records but to fetch last records it takes 6 seconds with above query. I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: How can i use it WITHOUT an order by clause in original query ?

Comment: is is better if we add `TOP 20` phrase to inner select query eg: `.. SELECT TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...`

Comment: @saeedserpooshan If you do this, you will get only the first 20 results and nothing more past that. The actual pagination ocurs because the inner query returns the row numbers for you to choose from.

Comment: @saeed serpooshan TOP cannot be parametrized with !at parameter!

Comment: @broadband - if you have 3,000,000 rows & you want to page to the end, you need to re-think the legitimacy of your use case (I find it hard to believe a *user* would sit there paging through 3,000,000 rows). And if you actually have a legitimately unavoidable requirement that allows users to page to the end (which i doubt), then you shouldn't be implementing paging this naively, you should have an efficient cursored solution (not a sql cursor) that requires some sort of ephemeral positional state persistence, not the cookie cutter solution posted here that solves 99% of cases.

Comment: @AaronHS I agree that user won't do paging till the last page, but just wanted to point out performance issues regarding large number of records. In the end I solved it by paging with Id. `select top 100 from table where id > 35400` and remembered last Id and for next page: `select top 100 from table where id > 35515`. Why is Id 35515 and not 35400. Let's just say that some records got deleted between 35400 and 35515. With this approach I got of course the same performance if there are 10 or 10 milion records in the database. Id column is primary key and auto increment (identity in ms sql).

Comment: this method sucs when you need to filter the row constrained result deeper e.g where customerName like '%Chris%' it just returns a fraction of the desired results

Comment: if you can  use primary key column in ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY PrimaryKeyCol )  , it will be the fastest . espacially  in table with 1M rows .

Comment: `Getting the total number of results and paginating are two different operations.`: They don't have to be. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14744475/109941

Comment: How should the column, `x`, be determined in `OVER ( ORDER BY x)`? I'm guessing that you, @mdb, chose `OrderDate` since it provides an ordering. However, what if there's no natural ordering in a table? Thanks

Comment: This solution returns all records regardless RowNum < 20. Something is not right.

Comment: Performance tip using TOP clause (assuming next code inside a stored procedure):
`SELECT TOP (@PageSize) *
FROM (SELECT TOP (@PageSize * @Page) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate 
) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      Orders
          WHERE     OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @Page * @PageSize `

Answer (score 692):

Finally, **Microsoft SQL Server 2012** was released, I really like its simplicity for a pagination, you don't have to use complex queries like answered here.

For getting the next 10 rows just run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned

Key points to consider when using it:

- `ORDER BY` is mandatory to use `OFFSET ... FETCH` clause.
- `OFFSET` clause is mandatory with `FETCH`. You cannot use `ORDER BY ...
  FETCH`.
- `TOP` cannot be combined with `OFFSET` and `FETCH` in the same query
  expression.

Comment: Still waiting on `LISTAGG()`/`GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: @BaconBits See this answer for a sneaky way of doing it with `FOR XML`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/429949

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir There's lots of problems with `FOR XML PATH ('')`.  First, it replaces XML control characters with XML entity codes.  Hope you don't have `<`, `>`, or `&` in your data!  Second, `FOR XML PATH ('')` used in this manner is actually undocumented syntax.  You're supposed to specify a named column or an alternate element name.  Doing neither is not in the doc, meaning the behavior is unreliable. Third, the more we accept the broken `FOR XML PATH ('')` syntax, the less likely it is that MS actually provides a *real* `LISTAGG() [ OVER() ]` function like they have needed to.

Comment: @BaconBits You can get around the encoding issue by using `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')` as in the answer. Anyways, I was simply showing a workaround that's relatively efficient until they add the feature into the core of SQL Server.

Comment: shame the perf is so bad http://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: @Jon, that linked blog post is not representative, in the sense it makes comparisons based on returning the page result by looking up values of the id column.

Comment: mssqlgirl article might be interesting for some.  Archived here for quick ref: https://web.archive.org/web/20190613101210/https://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012.html

Answer (score 145):

Incredibly, no other answer has mentioned the *fastest* way to do pagination in all SQL Server versions. Offsets can be terribly slow for large page numbers as is [benchmarked here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml). There is an entirely different, much faster way to perform pagination in SQL. This is often called the "seek method" or "keyset pagination" as described in [this blog post here](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/).

```
SELECT TOP 10 first_name, last_name, score, COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM players
WHERE (score < @previousScore)
   OR (score = @previousScore AND player_id < @previousPlayerId)
ORDER BY score DESC, player_id DESC
```

#### The "seek predicate"

The `@previousScore` and `@previousPlayerId` values are the respective values of the last record from the previous page. This allows you to fetch the "next" page. If the `ORDER BY` direction is `ASC`, simply use `>` instead.

With the above method, you cannot immediately jump to page 4 without having first fetched the previous 40 records. But often, you do not want to jump that far anyway. Instead, you get a much faster query that might be able to fetch data in constant time, depending on your indexing. Plus, your pages remain "stable", no matter if the underlying data changes (e.g. on page 1, while you're on page 4).

This is the best way to implement pagination when lazy loading more data in web applications, for instance.

Note, the "seek method" is also called [keyset pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215973/521799).

#### Total records before pagination

The `COUNT(*) OVER()` window function will help you count the number of total records "before pagination". If you're using SQL Server 2000, you will have to resort to two queries for the `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: What about SQl SERVER 2012 LIMIT FETCH/OFFSET?

Comment: @user960567: In terms of performance, keyset paging will always beat offset paging, no matter whether you implement offset paging with the SQL standard `OFFSET .. FETCH`, or with previous `ROW_NUMBER()` tricks.

Comment: Lukas, from my testing `WITH C AS(SELECT TOP(@rowsPerPage * @pageNum), ResultNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)...) SELECT *
FROM C
WHERE ResultNum > ((@pageNum - 1) * @rowsPerPage)` was fastest. http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/best-sql-server-pagination-method

Comment: For what value of `@pageNum`? Be sure to read [this whole article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page). You'll see that offset paging won't beat keyset paging, even if it can *appear* fast for low offsets.

Comment: upto thousands page numbers

Comment: I have tried first which was taking upto 3 seconds. The `WITH C AS` takes only 1 ms.

Comment: Well, you do have appropriate indexes set in place for keyset paging, right? :-)

Comment: I have added no index in my table so fast

Comment: I have three issues with the seek method. [1] A user can't jump to page. [2] it assumes sequential keys i.e. if someone deletes some 3 rows, then I get a page of 7 items instead of 10. `RowNumber` gives me a consistent 10 items per page. [3] it doesn't work with existing grids that assume `pagenumber` and `pagesize`.

Comment: @Junto: [1] correct, but this isn't always needed. You can still "emulate" jumping to the next few pages by making the actual page number bigger than the one displayed to the user. [2] That shouldn't happen, perhaps you don't have a unique sort criteria? [3] That's correct. But related to the OP's question, that wasn't really a requirement..

Comment: @Junto: keyset paging isn't appropriate for all cases. It's definitely not for data grids. But it's perfect for scenarios like infinite scrolling of Facebook feed page. Doesn't matter if new posts are being added at the top, your subsequent feed posts will be correctly added to the bottom while you're scrolling down. Perfect usage example for this... Such thing would be much **much** harder to implement using offset limit/fetch using numbers only.

Comment: I have to agree with Junto. This method completely rules out a client that has a pretty standard pagination ui of "Previous 1 2 3 (4) 5 6 Next" where users can jump ahead. This is not exactly an edge case in my experience...

Comment: This is the key feature I was looking for: `COUNT(*) OVER()`

Comment: Keyset pagination article [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: @Stphane It's not wrong, but IMHO quite useless article (have read it before). The trouble is, that it doesn't explain, how to do a useful, real-world queries (i.e. with filtering entries). It's doable with keyset approach, but painful, like in one of the answer above. Speed is falliing to. Not exactly a win-win situation, as it often seems to be presented.

Comment: @Oak_3260548: [Use jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/) to get access to a simple syntax for no-pain keyset paginatino.

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 53):

From SQL Server 2012, we can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` Clause to achieve the pagination.

Try this, for SQL Server:

> In the SQL Server 2012 a new feature was added in the ORDER BY clause,
>   to query optimization of a set data, making work easier with data
>   paging for anyone who writes in T-SQL as well for the entire Execution
>   Plan in SQL Server.
>
> Below the T-SQL script with the same logic used in the previous
>   example.
>
> ```
> --CREATING A PAGING WITH OFFSET and FETCH clauses IN "SQL SERVER 2012"
> DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
> SET @PageNumber = 2
> SET @RowspPage = 10 
> SELECT ID_EXAMPLE, NM_EXAMPLE, DT_CREATE
> FROM TB_EXAMPLE
> ORDER BY ID_EXAMPLE
> OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
> FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY;
> ```

[TechNet: Paging a Query with SQL Server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: most accurate answer in this trial

Comment: @Vikrant only if you if you ignore all the people running lower version than 2012

Comment: The question also asks for total number of rows before paging, which this answer does not answer.

Answer (score 20):

[MSDN: ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.
>
> The following example returns rows with numbers 50 to 60 inclusive in the order of the OrderDate.

```sql
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FirstName DESC) AS RowNumber, 
        FirstName, LastName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1) AS "Sales YTD"
    FROM [dbo].[vSalesPerson]
) 
SELECT RowNumber, 
    FirstName, LastName, Sales YTD 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber > 50 AND RowNumber < 60;
```

```
  RowNumber FirstName    LastName               SalesYTD
  --- -----------  ---------------------- -----------------
  1   Linda        Mitchell               4251368.54
  2   Jae          Pak                    4116871.22
  3   Michael      Blythe                 3763178.17
  4   Jillian      Carson                 3189418.36
  5   Ranjit       Varkey Chudukatil      3121616.32
  6   José         Saraiva                2604540.71
  7   Shu          Ito                    2458535.61
  8   Tsvi         Reiter                 2315185.61
  9   Rachel       Valdez                 1827066.71
  10  Tete         Mensa-Annan            1576562.19
  11  David        Campbell               1573012.93
  12  Garrett      Vargas                 1453719.46
  13  Lynn         Tsoflias               1421810.92
  14  Pamela       Ansman-Wolfe           1352577.13
```

Comment: The question also asks for total number of rows before paging, which this answer does not answer.

Answer (score 16):

There is a good overview of different paging techniques at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingLarge.aspx

I've used ROWCOUNT method quite often mostly with SQL Server 2000 (will work with 2005 & 2008 too, just measure performance compared to ROW_NUMBER), it's lightning fast, but you need to make sure that the sorted column(s) have  (mostly) unique values.

Comment: Interestingly, that article doesn't mention the [seek method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609938/521799), which is able to perform paging in constant time... Still a good article

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2000 you can simulate ROW_NUMBER() using a table variable with an IDENTITY column:

```
DECLARE @pageNo int -- 1 based
DECLARE @pageSize int
SET @pageNo = 51
SET @pageSize = 20

DECLARE @firstRecord int
DECLARE @lastRecord int
SET @firstRecord = (@pageNo - 1) * @pageSize + 1 -- 1001
SET @lastRecord = @firstRecord + @pageSize - 1   -- 1020

DECLARE @orderedKeys TABLE (
  rownum int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  TableKey int NOT NULL
)

SET ROWCOUNT @lastRecord
INSERT INTO @orderedKeys (TableKey) SELECT ID FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '1980-01-01' ORDER BY OrderDate

SET ROWCOUNT 0

SELECT t.*
FROM Orders t
  INNER JOIN @orderedKeys o ON o.TableKey = t.ID
WHERE o.rownum >= @firstRecord
ORDER BY o.rownum
```

This approach can be extended to tables with multi-column keys, and it doesn't incur the performance overhead of using OR (which skips index usage).  The downside is the amount of temporary space used up if the data set is very large and one is near the last page.  I did not test cursor performance in that case, but it might be better.

Note that this approach could be optimized for the first page of data.  Also, ROWCOUNT was used since TOP does not accept a variable in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3):

Use case wise the following seem to be easy to use and fast. Just set the page number.

```
use AdventureWorks
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 10, @PageNumber INT = 6;
with result as(
SELECT SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderID, ProductID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesOrderDetailID) AS RowNum
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where 1=1
)
select SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderID, ProductID from result
WHERE result.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)
```

also without CTE

```
use AdventureWorks
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 10, @PageNumber INT = 6
SELECT SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderID, ProductID
FROM (
SELECT SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderID, ProductID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesOrderDetailID) AS RowNum
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where 1=1
 ) AS SOD
WHERE SOD.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)
```

Comment: What does where 1=1 do sir?

Comment: It's a placeholder for where clause. You can easily add more clauses with `AND` on new lines and comment or remove them if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The best way for paging in sql server 2012 is by using offset and fetch next in a stored procedure.
**OFFSET Keyword** -  If we use offset with the order by clause then the query will skip the number of records we specified in OFFSET n Rows.

**FETCH NEXT Keywords** - When we use Fetch Next with an order by clause only it will returns the no of rows you want to display in paging, without Offset then SQL will generate an error.
here is the example given below.

```
create procedure sp_paging
(
 @pageno as int,
 @records as int
)
as
begin
declare @offsetcount as int
set @offsetcount=(@pageno-1)*@records
select id,bs,variable from salary order by id offset @offsetcount rows fetch Next @records rows only
end
```

you can execute it as follow.

```
exec sp_paging 2,3
```

Answer (score 3):

From 2012 onward we can use 
`OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Answer (score 2):

These are my solutions for paging the result of query in SQL server side.
these approaches are different between SQL Server 2008 and 2012.
Also, I have added the concept of filtering and order by with one column. It is very efficient when you are paging and filtering and ordering in your Gridview.

Before testing, you have to create one sample table and insert some row in this table : (In real world you have to change Where clause considering your table fields and maybe you have some join and subquery in main part of select)

```
Create Table VLT
(
    ID int IDentity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Tel Varchar(20)
)
GO


Insert INTO VLT
VALUES
    ('NAME' + Convert(varchar(10),@@identity),'FAMIL' + Convert(varchar(10),@@identity))
GO 500000
```

In all of these sample, I want to query 200 rows per page and I am fetching the row for page number 1200.

In SQL server 2008, you can use the CTE concept. Because of that, I have written two type of query for SQL server 2008+

-- SQL Server 2008+

```
DECLARE @PageNumber Int = 1200
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 200
DECLARE @SortByField int = 1 --The field used for sort by
DECLARE @SortOrder nvarchar(255) = 'ASC' --ASC or DESC
DECLARE @FilterType nvarchar(255) = 'None' --The filter type, as defined on the client side (None/Contain/NotContain/Match/NotMatch/True/False/)
DECLARE @FilterValue nvarchar(255) = '' --The value the user gave for the filter
DECLARE @FilterColumn int = 1 --The column to wich the filter is applied, represents the column number like when we send the information.

SELECT 
  Data.ID,
  Data.Name,
  Data.Tel
FROM
  (  
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER( ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.ID END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.ID END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.Name END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.Name END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.Tel END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.Tel END ASC
         ) AS RowNum
      ,*  
    FROM VLT 
    WHERE
      ( -- We apply the filter logic here
        CASE
          WHEN @FilterType = 'None' THEN 1

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID <> @FilterValue THEN 1               

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name <> @FilterValue THEN 1         

         -- Tel column filter   
         WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel <> @FilterValue THEN 1    

        END
      ) = 1   
  ) AS Data
WHERE Data.RowNum > @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1)
  AND Data.RowNum <= @PageSize * @PageNumber
ORDER BY Data.RowNum

GO
```

And second solution with CTE in SQL server 2008+

```
DECLARE @PageNumber Int = 1200
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 200
DECLARE @SortByField int = 1 --The field used for sort by
DECLARE @SortOrder nvarchar(255) = 'ASC' --ASC or DESC
DECLARE @FilterType nvarchar(255) = 'None' --The filter type, as defined on the client side (None/Contain/NotContain/Match/NotMatch/True/False/)
DECLARE @FilterValue nvarchar(255) = '' --The value the user gave for the filter
DECLARE @FilterColumn int = 1 --The column to wich the filter is applied, represents the column number like when we send the information.

;WITH
  Data_CTE
  AS
  (  
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER( ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.ID END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.ID END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.Name END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.Name END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                      THEN VLT.Tel END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                      THEN VLT.Tel END ASC
         ) AS RowNum
      ,*  
    FROM VLT
    WHERE
      ( -- We apply the filter logic here
        CASE
          WHEN @FilterType = 'None' THEN 1

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID <> @FilterValue THEN 1               

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name <> @FilterValue THEN 1         

         -- Tel column filter   
         WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel <> @FilterValue THEN 1    

        END
      ) = 1     
  )

SELECT 
  Data.ID,
  Data.Name,
  Data.Tel
FROM Data_CTE AS Data
WHERE Data.RowNum > @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1)
  AND Data.RowNum <= @PageSize * @PageNumber
ORDER BY Data.RowNum
```

-- SQL Server 2012+

```
DECLARE @PageNumber Int = 1200
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 200
DECLARE @SortByField int = 1 --The field used for sort by
DECLARE @SortOrder nvarchar(255) = 'ASC' --ASC or DESC
DECLARE @FilterType nvarchar(255) = 'None' --The filter type, as defined on the client side (None/Contain/NotContain/Match/NotMatch/True/False/)
DECLARE @FilterValue nvarchar(255) = '' --The value the user gave for the filter
DECLARE @FilterColumn int = 1 --The column to wich the filter is applied, represents the column number like when we send the information.

;WITH
  Data_CTE
  AS
  (  
    SELECT 
      *  
    FROM VLT
    WHERE
      ( -- We apply the filter logic here
        CASE
          WHEN @FilterType = 'None' THEN 1

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.ID NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 1
            AND VLT.ID <> @FilterValue THEN 1               

          -- Name column filter
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Name NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 2
            AND VLT.Name <> @FilterValue THEN 1         

         -- Tel column filter   
         WHEN @FilterType = 'Contain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotContain' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND ( -- In this case, when the filter value is empty, we want to show everything.
                VLT.Tel NOT LIKE '%' + @FilterValue + '%'
               OR
                @FilterValue = ''
               ) THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'Match' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel = @FilterValue THEN 1
          WHEN @FilterType = 'NotMatch' AND @FilterColumn = 3
            AND VLT.Tel <> @FilterValue THEN 1    

        END
      ) = 1         
  )

SELECT 
  Data.ID,
  Data.Name,
  Data.Tel
FROM Data_CTE AS Data
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
        THEN Data.ID END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 1 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
        THEN Data.ID END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
        THEN Data.Name END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 2 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
        THEN Data.Name END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'ASC'
        THEN Data.Tel END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortByField = 3 AND @SortOrder = 'DESC'
        THEN Data.Tel END ASC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
SELECT TOP @offset a.*
FROM (select top @limit b.*, COUNT(*) OVER() totalrows 
        from TABLENAME b order by id asc) a
ORDER BY id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have used the following sample query in my SQL 2000 database, it works well for SQL 2005 too. The power it gives you is dynamically order by using multiple columns. 
I tell you ... this is powerful :)

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RE_ListingReports_SelectSummary] 

@CompanyID  int,
@pageNumber     int,
@pageSize   int, 
@sort       varchar(200)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @strPageSize nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @strSkippedRows nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @strFields nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @strFilter nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @sortBy nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @strFrom nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @strID nvarchar(100)

If(@pageNumber < 0)
  SET @pageNumber = 1
SET @strPageSize = CAST(@pageSize AS varchar(20)) 
SET @strSkippedRows = CAST(((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) AS varchar(20))-- For    example if pageNumber is 5  pageSize is 10, then SkippedRows = 40.
SET @strID = 'ListingDbID'
SET @strFields = 'ListingDbID,
ListingID,  
[ExtraRoom]
'
SET @strFrom = ' vwListingSummary '

SET @strFilter = ' WHERE
        CompanyID = ' + CAST(@CompanyID As varchar(20)) 
End
SET @sortBy = ''
if(len(ltrim(rtrim(@sort))) > 0)
SET @sortBy = ' Order By ' + @sort

-- Total Rows Count

SET @sql =  'SELECT Count(' + @strID + ')  FROM ' + @strFROM + @strFilter
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

--// This technique is used in a Single Table pagination
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @strFields + ' FROM ' + @strFROM +
    ' WHERE ' + @strID +  ' IN ' + 
   '  (SELECT TOP ' + @strPageSize + ' ' + @strID + ' FROM ' + @strFROM + @strFilter + 
             ' AND  ' + @strID + ' NOT IN ' + '
          (SELECT TOP ' + @strSkippedRows + ' ' + @strID + ' FROM ' + @strFROM + @strFilter + @SortBy + ') ' 
   + @SortBy + ') ' + @SortBy
Print @sql 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

The best part is sp_executesql caches later calls, provided you pass same parameters i.e generate same sql text.

Answer (score 0):

```
   CREATE view vw_sppb_part_listsource as 
    select row_number() over (partition by sppb_part.init_id order by sppb_part.sppb_part_id asc ) as idx, * from (
      select 
          part.SPPB_PART_ID
          , 0 as is_rev
          , part.part_number 
          , part.init_id 
      from t_sppb_init_part part 
      left join t_sppb_init_partrev prev on ( part.SPPB_PART_ID = prev.SPPB_PART_ID )
      where prev.SPPB_PART_ID is null 
      union 
      select 
          part.SPPB_PART_ID
          , 1 as is_rev
          , prev.part_number 
          , part.init_id 
      from t_sppb_init_part part 
      inner join t_sppb_init_partrev prev on ( part.SPPB_PART_ID = prev.SPPB_PART_ID )
    ) sppb_part
```

will restart idx when it comes to different init_id

Answer (score 0):

> FROM [TableX]
> ORDER BY [FieldX]
> OFFSET 500 ROWS
> FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY

[Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) the topic is discussed in greater details, and with alternate approaches.

Answer (score -1):

For the `ROW_NUMBER` technique, if you do not have a sorting column to use, you can use the [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4
FROM (
    SELECT 
         tbl.col1 AS col1
        ,tbl.col2 AS col2
        ,tbl.col3 AS col3
        ,tbl.col4 AS col4
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ) AS sort_row
    FROM dbo.MyTable tbl
    ) AS query
WHERE query.sort_row > 10
ORDER BY query.sort_row
```

This has worked well for me for searches over table sizes of even up to 700,000.

**This fetches records 11 to 30.**

Comment: As a good practice, with pagination you should try to order by a unique set of columns in the result set since order should not be thought of as guaranteed.

Comment: This fetches records 11 to 30.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> create PROCEDURE SP_Company_List (@pagesize int = -1 ,@pageindex int= 0   ) > AS BEGIN  SET NOCOUNT ON;
>
>
>     select  Id , NameEn     from Company  ORDER by Id ASC  
> OFFSET (@pageindex-1 )* @pagesize   ROWS FETCH NEXt @pagesize ROWS ONLY END  GO
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> DECLARE   @return_value int
>
> EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[SP_Company_List]         @pagesize = 1 ,         > @pageindex = 2
>
> SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value
>
> GO
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This bit gives you ability to paginate using SQL Server, and newer versions of MySQL and carries the total number of rows in every row.
Uses your pimary key to count number of unique rows.

```
WITH T AS
(  
  SELECT TABLE_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_ID) AS RN
  , (SELECT COUNT(TABLE_ID) FROM TABLE) AS TOTAL 
  FROM TABLE (NOLOCK)
)

SELECT T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3, T.TOTAL 
FROM TABLE T2 (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN T ON T2.TABLE_ID=T.TABLE_ID
WHERE T.RN >= 100
AND T.RN < 200
```

Comment: Can you please leave any comments that explain what your code does?

Answer (score -21):

You didn't specify the language nor which driver you are using. Therefore I'm describing it abstractly.

- Create a scrollable resultset / dataset. This required a primary on the table(s)
- jump to the end
- request the row count
- jump to the start of the page
- scroll through the rows until the end of the page