# efficient way to implement paging

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, pagination

Should I use LINQ's `Skip()` and `Take()` method for paging, or implement my own paging with a SQL query?

Which is most efficient? Why would I choose one over the other?

I'm using SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET MVC and LINQ.

Comment: I think it depends. What can of app are you working on? what kind of load will it have?

Comment: Take a look on this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10639172/416996

Comment: Take a look this also http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Trying to give you a brief answer to your doubt, if you execute the `skip(n).take(m)` methods on linq (with SQL 2005 / 2008 as database server) your query will be using the `Select ROW_NUMBER() Over ...` statement, with is somehow direct paging in the SQL engine.

Giving you an example, I have a db table called `mtcity` and I wrote the following query (work as well with linq to entities):

```csh
using (DataClasses1DataContext c = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var query = (from MtCity2 c1 in c.MtCity2s
                select c1).Skip(3).Take(3);
    //Doing something with the query.
}
```

The resulting query will be:

```sql
SELECT [t1].[CodCity], 
    [t1].[CodCountry], 
    [t1].[CodRegion], 
    [t1].[Name],  
    [t1].[Code]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY [t0].[CodCity], 
        [t0].[CodCountry], 
        [t0].[CodRegion], 
        [t0].[Name],
        [t0].[Code]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], 
        [t0].[CodCity], 
        [t0].[CodCountry], 
        [t0].[CodRegion], 
        [t0].[Name],
        [t0].[Code]
    FROM [dbo].[MtCity] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Which is a windowed data access (pretty cool, btw cuz will be returning data since the very begining and will access the table as long as the conditions are met). This will be very similar to:

```sql
With CityEntities As 
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By CodCity) As Row,
        CodCity //here is only accessed by the Index as CodCity is the primary
    From dbo.mtcity
)
Select [t0].[CodCity], 
        [t0].[CodCountry], 
        [t0].[CodRegion], 
        [t0].[Name],
        [t0].[Code]
From CityEntities c
Inner Join dbo.MtCity t0 on c.CodCity = t0.CodCity
Where c.Row Between @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
Order By c.Row Asc
```

With the exception that, this second query will be executed faster than the linq result because it will be using exclusively the index to create the data access window; this means, if you need some filtering, the filtering should be (or must be) in the Entity listing (where the row is created) and some indexes should be created as well to keep up the good performance.

Now, whats better?

If you have pretty much solid workflow in your logic, implementing the proper SQL way will be complicated. In that case LINQ will be the solution.

If you can lower that part of the logic directly to SQL (in a stored procedure), it will be even better because you can implement the second query I showed you (using indexes) and allow SQL to generate and store the Execution Plan of the query (improving performance).

Comment: Nice answer - common table expression is a good way to do paging.

Comment: Could you check my question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100929/asp-net-mvc-webgrid-efficent-paging/11104822#comment14552347_11104822)? I made a SP that I added to my EDMX and used it in a linq-to-entities query.

Comment: +1, good answer, I appreciate you explain the performance benefits of the second example

Comment: @Johan: There is an alternative called the [seek method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609720/521799) that heavily outperforms offsets for large page numbers.

Answer (score 52):

Try using

```
FROM [TableX]
ORDER BY [FieldX]
OFFSET 500 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

to get the rows from 501 to 600 in the SQL server, without loading them in memory. Note that this syntax has become available with [SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) only

Comment: I think this is incorrect. The SQL displayed shows rows from 502-601 (unless you're zero-indexing?)

Comment: No it does get rows from 501 to 600

Answer (score 13):

While LINQ-to-SQL will generate an `OFFSET` clause (possibly emulated using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` [as others have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658570/521799)), there is an entirely different, much faster way to perform paging in SQL. This is often called the "seek method" as described in [this blog post here](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/).

```
SELECT TOP 10 first_name, last_name, score
FROM players
WHERE (score < @previousScore)
   OR (score = @previousScore AND player_id < @previousPlayerId)
ORDER BY score DESC, player_id DESC
```

The `@previousScore` and `@previousPlayerId` values are the respective values of the last record from the previous page. This allows you to fetch the "next" page. If the `ORDER BY` direction is `ASC`, simply use `>` instead.

With the above method, you cannot immediately jump to page 4 without having first fetched the previous 40 records. But often, you do not want to jump that far anyway. Instead, you get a much faster query that might be able to fetch data in constant time, depending on your indexing. Plus, your pages remain "stable", no matter if the underlying data changes (e.g. on page 1, while you're on page 4).

This is the best way to implement paging when lazy loading more data in web applications, for instance.

Note, the "seek method" is also called [keyset paging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215973/521799).

Answer (score 5):

LinqToSql will automatically convert a .Skip(N1).Take(N2) into the TSQL syntax for you.  In fact, every "query" you do in Linq, is actually just creating a SQL query for you in the background.  To test this, just run SQL Profiler while your application is running.

The skip/take methodology has worked very well for me, and others from what I read.

Out of curiosity, what type of self-paging query do you have, that you believe is more efficient than Linq's skip/take?

Answer (score 4):

We use a CTE wrapped in Dynamic SQL (because our application requires dynamic sorting of data server side) within a stored procedure.  I can provide a basic example if you'd like.

I haven't had a chance to look at the T/SQL that LINQ produces.  Can someone post a sample?

We don't use LINQ or straight access to the tables as we require the extra layer of security (granted the dynamic SQL breaks this somewhat).

Something like this should do the trick.  You can add in parameterized values for parameters, etc.

```
exec sp_executesql 'WITH MyCTE AS (
    SELECT TOP (10) ROW_NUMBER () OVER ' + @SortingColumn + ' as RowID, Col1, Col2
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Col4 = ''Something''
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
WHERE RowID BETWEEN 10 and 20'
```

Comment: @mrdenny - One **hint for the example** you've provided: With `sp_executesql` you have the possibility to pass parameters in a secure way, e.g.: `EXECUTE sp_executesql 'WITH myCTE AS ... WHERE Col4=@p1) ...', '@p1 nvarchar(max)', @ValueForCol4`. Secure in this context means it is robust against SQL injection - you can pass every possible value inside the variable `@ValueForCol4` - even `'--'`, and the query will still work!

Comment: @mrdenny   Hi, instead of concatenating the query we use something like this:  `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN @CampoId = 1 THEN Id
WHEN @CampoId = 2 THEN field2
END)`

Comment: That can produce some awful SQL Execution plans.

Comment: @mrdenny: For large page numbers, the [seek method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609720/521799) can be much faster than `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` offset emulation. See also: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @PAGE INTEGER = 2
DECLARE @TAKE INTEGER = 50

SELECT [t1].*
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[COLUMNORDER] DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].*
    FROM [dbo].[TABLA] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[COLUMNS_CONDITIONS] = 1)
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN ((@PAGE*@TAKE) - (@TAKE-1)) AND (@PAGE*@TAKE)
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

In t0 are all records
In t1 are only those corresponding to that page

Answer (score 2):

The approach that I am giving is the fastest pagination that SQL server can achieve. I have tested this on 5 million records. This approach is far better than "OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY" provided by SQL Server.

```
-- The below given code computes the page numbers and the max row of previous page
-- Replace <<>> with the correct table data.
-- Eg. <<IdentityColumn of Table>> can be EmployeeId and <<Table>> will be dbo.Employees

DECLARE @PageNumber int=1; --1st/2nd/nth page. In stored proc take this as input param.
DECLARE @NoOfRecordsPerPage int=1000;

 DECLARE @PageDetails TABLE
       (
        <<IdentityColumn of Table>> int,
        rownum int,
        [PageNumber] int
       )           
       INSERT INTO @PageDetails values(0, 0, 0)
       ;WITH CTE AS
       (
       SELECT <<IdentityColumn of Table>>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <<IdentityColumn of Table>>) rownum FROM <<Table>>
       )
       Insert into @PageDetails 
       SELECT <<IdentityColumn of Table>>, CTE.rownum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rownum) as [PageNumber] FROM CTE WHERE CTE.rownum%@NoOfRecordsPerPage=0


--SELECT * FROM @PageDetails 

-- Actual pagination
SELECT TOP (@NoOfRecordsPerPage)
FROM <<Table>> AS <<Table>>
WHERE <<IdentityColumn of Table>> > (SELECT <<IdentityColumn of Table>> FROM 
@PageDetails WHERE PageNumber=@PageNumber)
ORDER BY <<Identity Column of Table>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can further improve the performance, chech this

```
From CityEntities c
Inner Join dbo.MtCity t0 on c.CodCity = t0.CodCity
Where c.Row Between @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
Order By c.Row Asc
```

if you will use the from in this way it will give better result:

```
From   dbo.MtCity  t0
   Inner Join  CityEntities c on c.CodCity = t0.CodCity
```

reason: because you are using the where class on the CityEntities table which will eliminate many record before joining the MtCity, so 100% sure it will increase the performance many fold...

Anyway answer by rodrigoelp is really helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt there will be any performance impact by using this advice.

Can't find a reference for this but inner join order in query can differ from actual join order. The latter is decided by query optimizer using table's statistics and operation cost estimations.

Comment: @ImreP: This might actually somewhat correspond to the [seek method, that I have described](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609720/521799). Although, I'm not sure where `@p0` and more specifically `@p1` come from

Answer (score 0):

You can implement paging in this  simple way by passing PageIndex

```
Declare @PageIndex INT = 1
Declare  @PageSize INT = 20

Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Products.Name ASC )  AS RowNumber,
    Products.ID,
    Products.Name
into #Result 
From Products

SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results 

SELECT * 
FROM #Results
WHERE RowNumber
BETWEEN
    (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
    AND
    (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2008 we cant use Skip().Take()

The way is:

```
var MinPageRank = (PageNumber - 1) * NumInPage + 1
var MaxPageRank = PageNumber * NumInPage

var visit = Visita.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM (SELECT [RANK] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Hora DESC),* FROM Visita WHERE ) A WHERE A.[RANK] BETWEEN {MinPageRank} AND {MaxPageRank}").ToList();
```