# Resource limit error in linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a problem with running a query in a linked server, I use sql sp’s for ETL process in my BI project
(For some reason I cannot use ssis).one of my queries  witch has to read recently changed records and insert them in my warehouse take too long to execute and always  fail with this error:

```
OLE DB provider 'SQLOLEDB' reported an error for linked server ‘XXX’. Execution terminated by the provider because a resource limit was reached..
```

But other queries  run successfully. I also run following scrip in my linked server (warehouse) to increase timeout threshold.

```
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 30
go
reconfigure with override
go

sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

Hint: I’ve used change tracking option in source tables to track updates and inserts..
I would be really thankful if someone could help me out of this.

Comment: The answers in these questions should help:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866257/retrieving-billions-of-rows-from-remote-server `and`  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/sql-performance-issues-with-remote-query-across-linked-server