# Wrapping any SQL Server 2008 statement with skip/take operators

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given any `SELECT` statement, I would like to wrap it with skip and take operators.

For instance, for Oracle I created this function:

```
public override string WrapSelectSqlWithPagination(string sql, int skipRows, int numberOfRows) 
{
    string innerSql = String.Format("select /* FIRST_ROWS(n) */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ({0}) a where ROWNUM <= {1}", sql, skipRows + numberOfRows);
    return String.Format("select * from ({0}) where rnum > {1}", innerSql, skipRows);
}
```

It works perfectly.

I would like to do the same thing for SQL Server, is it possible?

**Mind that I don't know anything about sorting in advance.**

Thanks.

Comment: I found this good link from SO which I hope overlaps with what you need?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging

Comment: You realize the `TOP` clause isn't relevant without an `ORDER BY`?  There is no guaranteed order in SQL.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But who needs to care about it is the one calling the function, not me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sql template to get the desired range of records for SQL.

```
WITH [AnyVariable] AS
(
select * ,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [Col1]) AS 'RowNum'
     from [Table1]
)
SELECT * FROM [AnyVariable]
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 6
```

Just replace the things in [] with your stuff. Remember to remove the []. And then use this in your method above.

Comment: This solution doesn't work since it requires to know the column used for sorting in advance :(

Comment: @andrecarlucci - I provided this solution before you updated your question. See the time of question update and the time I answered. I can update the answer soon.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I got it. It's probably very slow but it works:

```
public override string WrapSelectSqlWithPagination(string sql, int skipRows, int numberOfRows) {
        Regex regex = new Regex("SELECT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        sql = regex.Replace(sql, "SELECT TOP 2147483647 ", 1);

        string innerSql =
            @"select * into #TempTable from (
                        select * ,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by aaa) AS rownum from (
                            select 'aaa' as aaa, * from  (
                                {0}
                            )as t1
                        )as t2
                    ) as t3
                where rownum between {1} and {2}
                alter table #TempTable drop column aaa
                alter table #TempTable drop column rownum
                select * from #TempTable
                drop table #TempTable
            ";
        return String.Format(innerSql, sql, skipRows+1, skipRows + numberOfRows);
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?