# sql query limit by amount of values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pagination

I work on a SQL Server 2005, where I have two tables, like this:

*Table1*

```
ID (Guid) Primarykey
something1 (string)
something2 (string)
```

And

*Table2*

```
ID (Guid) Primarykey
Table1ID (Guid) is a ForeignKey to Table1
OrderNr (int)
something1 (string)
something2 (string)
```

Now I have to do a select query (which gives me hundreds of results), basically something like: `SELECT * from Table2 where something1 = 'foo' order by Table1ID, OrderNr`

Specially the order by is important, I can't change that. And the statement is in real much more complicated with a lot of joins, subselects and wheres and so on, but they are not needed here...

My problem is, that I need a special paging: Just select all the rows with the 20 different Table1IDs starting from ID 10 to ID 15. (That means **I want a paging, but not on rowcount but on this columns unique values**)

If I had a nested select or a function call which adds the iterated number of the selectstatement i could use a between, but how can I count the unique ids and add it to the query up there?

Thank you for your help, Karl

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/658570/393908.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Why should a LINQ answer answer a sql question?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, because the answer also includes how to do it in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is similar to what Tim Schmelter said, but not a **`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY`**... but a **`DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Table1ID) AS rank`**

Explanation: DENSE_RANK does exactly what I want. It ranks the table, in my case by Table1ID. The effect is, each Table1ID got its own ranknumber. With **`rank between 10 and 15`** I get exactly what I wanted.

Tank you, Karl

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it's the better one. `DENSE_RANK()` is a very useful, lesser-known ranking function. Here's an [interesting blog post I've written recently](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/), explaining how `DENSE_RANK()` relates to `SELECT DISTINCT` the way `ROW_NUMBER()` relates to `SELECT`. That's not exactly the problem you're solving but might add some interesting background info

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `Partition By`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELCT Columns, ...
       , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table1IDs ORDER BY ID)
   FROM dbo.Table
)
SELECT Columns, ...
FROM CTE
WHERE RN BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

(or i have misunderstood your requirement which is not very unlikely)

Comment: Tahnk you, with your answer you helped me a lot. It was not that, what I needed but I came to the right websites due to your answer ;)