# Limit the records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have this function that display records from the database to flowlayoutpanel

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            myDatabaseConnection.Open();
            string a = "Select EmpID, Name from EmpTable";
            using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" "+ a +" ", myDatabaseConnection))
            {
                int i = 0;
                SqlDataReader DR1 = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (DR1.Read())
                {
                    i++;
                    BookUserControl usercontrol = new BookUserControl();
                    usercontrol.Tag = i;
                    usercontrol.EmpID = DR1["EmpID"].ToString();
                    usercontrol.Name = (string)DR1["Name"];
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
                }
            }
        }
```

How i will limit the number of records that will be display in the flowlayoutpanel? I know there is select top . But how I will do this, for example a number of 10 records will be display and when a nextbutton is click the next 10 records will be display and when a previousbutton is click the previous 10 records will be display.

Comment: What is your database? Oracle, Sql Server 2000/2005/2008?

Comment: This help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/658570/1134076

Comment: @SquarePonge - My answer did not work? I am curious, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `Row_Number()`:

```
Select * from    
(Select row_number() over (order by EmpID) r,  EmpID, Name from EmpTable) X
where X.r between @start and @end
```

Supply the values of `@start` and `@end` and you are all set. You may or may not display the value of `r`. To show from `1-10`, set `@start = 1` and `@end = 10` and so on and so forth. In this query the data is ordered on `EmpID`.

Modified code:

```
string a = "Select * from (Select row_number() over (order by EmpID) r,  EmpID, Name from EmpTable) X where X.r between @start and @end";
        using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" "+ a +" ", myDatabaseConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@start").Value = 1;
            SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@end").Value = 10;
            int i = 0;
            SqlDataReader DR1 = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR1.Read())
            {
                i++;
                BookUserControl usercontrol = new BookUserControl();
                usercontrol.Tag = i;
                usercontrol.EmpID = DR1["EmpID"].ToString();
                usercontrol.Name = (string)DR1["Name"];
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
            }
        }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes there is SELECT TOP in SQl

use it like this

```
Select TOP(10) EmpID, Name from EmpTable
```

i am updating your cod

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            myDatabaseConnection.Open();
            string a = "SELECT TOP(10) EmpID, Name FROM EmpTable";
            using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" "+ a +" ", myDatabaseConnection))
            {
                int i = 0;
                SqlDataReader DR1 = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (DR1.Read())
                {
                    i++;
                    BookUserControl usercontrol = new BookUserControl();
                    usercontrol.Tag = i;
                    usercontrol.EmpID = DR1["EmpID"].ToString();
                    usercontrol.Name = (string)DR1["Name"];
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(usercontrol);
                }
            }
        }
```

now use this cod and this will work exactly you want

best of luck

Comment: How about the next top 10? previous top 10?

Comment: That won't work! That will just repeat the same top 10 when he clicks next. What he's after is SQL paging or perhaps load all the results into a List<> then use .Take(10) etc.

Comment: this is the anser only for the top(n) record

Comment: if you want to create a system like NEXT and PREVIOUS

Comment: i am posting a new answer for this

Comment: What you proposed won't work for a next and previous as you are not keeping track of row number? You need to define it as a stored procedure (most likely) where you pass it current row_number() so the procedure knows what rows to return next. Yours will return the first 10 rows all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You the most elegant is to use the ROW_NUMBER function

```
WITH NumberedMyTable AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        MyTable
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Value
FROM
    NumberedMyTable
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN @From AND @To
```

best of luck