# Selecting n Number of Rows Starting From The nth Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL-noobie here that wants to modify the following stored procedure into one that selects a specified amount of rows starting from the specified row. For example I want to select 5 rows starting from the 10th row, ie 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15.

Here is what my SP looks like atm:

```
SELECT Posts.Slug, Comments.commentId, Comments.[date], Comments.name, Comments.[text]
FROM Comments 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Comments.postId = Posts.Id
WHERE Comments.approved = 0
```

I don't need to order the results as I want to read sequentially, in-case that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think "sequentially" means? Ordered by WHAT?

Comment: Also what you want to is called [paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging).

Comment: Sequentially as in the order by which they were stored in the database.

Comment: In your case, the ordering does matter as without order, the results can vary on different executions.  You're basically looking for paging.  In this case you just need to order, and then use RowNum to get slices:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server

Comment: "I don't need to order the results as I want to read sequentially, in-case that matters" This sentence contridicts itself, you'd be better off removing it.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't maintain the order by which they were stored in the database. Consider a table an unordered bag of rows. If you want to order by something, you need to tell SQL Server what that is. In this case I assume `[date]` as long as that's just a poor name and it actually includes time as well.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I was under the assumption that rows are stored in sequential order and then retrieved in that same order. I will start ordering by date then, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005/2008, you'll need to use a row number, as Maurice mentioned. The LIMIT syntax unfortunately doesn't work. The query will look like this (assuming you want to order by date)

```
WITH numbered AS
(
    SELECT 
       Posts.Slug, 
       Comments.commentId, 
       Comments.[date],
       Comments.name, Comments.[text],  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) as rownum
    FROM Comments 
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Comments.postId = Posts.Id
    WHERE Comments.approved = 0
) 
SELECT * FROM numbered WHERE rownum BETWEEN @startrow AND @endrow
```

The above assumes @startrow and @endrow are parameters passed into your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks man it works, I just had to change the last part as I didn't want to select the `rownum` :).

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be using SQL Server 2012 you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` for paging, but they require an `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT Posts.Slug, Comments.commentId, Comments.[date], Comments.name, Comments.[text]
FROM Comments 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Comments.postId = Posts.Id
WHERE Comments.approved = 0
ORDER BY [date]
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

If not using SQL Server 2012, the `ROW_NUMBER()` approach is how you should go.

If you actually want arbitrary ordering, you can use `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` but consistency cannot be guaranteed without explicit ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I decided to go with the `ROW_NUMBER()` thing for better compatibility. Still this works so cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Indeed the fastest for sql server is

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

Take a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506081930/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041206-1.shtml)

Comment: This is functionally no different than Daniel Neal's answer

Comment: @swasheck It is not actually the same. And I have added you a reference for further reading and understanding the statement. Sorry for that anyway

Comment: How is it different, except that you used a derived table instead of a CTE, and you didn't bother using the OP's actual table names?

Comment: @LefterisBab They're both table expressions. Thanks for the link to a 2006 ASP article, though.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote you. I just put a comment noting that it was a poor duplicate of an extant answer.

Comment: No hard feelings I searched to stackoverflow and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-sql-server

So I this this question is duplicate. Wright ?

Comment: Yes. That's why we VtC it.

Answer (score -3):

Use ROW_NUMBER() function in t-sql. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```