# Efficiently paging large data sets with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When looking into the best ways to implement paging in C# (using LINQ), most suggestions are something along these lines:

```
// Execute the query
var query = db.Entity.Where(e => e.Something == something);

// Get the total num records
var total = query.Count();

// Page the results
var paged = query.Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

This seems to be the commonly suggested strategy (simplified).

For me, my main purpose in paging is for efficiency. If my table contains 1.2 million records where Something == something, I don't want to retrieve all of them at the same time. Instead, I want to page the data, grabbing as few records as possible. But with this method, it seems that this is a moot point.

**If I understand it correctly, the first statement is still retrieving the 1.2 million records, *then* it is being paged as necessary.**

**Does paging in this way actually improve performance? If the 1.2 million records are going to be retrieved every time, what's the point (besides the obvious UI benefits)?**

Am I misunderstanding this? Any .NET gurus out there that can give me a lesson on LINQ, paging, and performance (when dealing with large data sets)?

Comment: @Mr.香港人 : No. Using `.Select` in Linq will not cause enumeration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first statement does not execute the actual SQL query, it only builds part of the query you intend to run.

It is when you call `query.Count()` that the first will be executed

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Something = something
```

On `query.Skip().Take()` won't execute the query either, it is only when you try to enumerate the results(doing a foreach over `paged` or calling `.ToList()` on it) that it will execute the appropriate SQL statement retrieving only the rows for the page (using ROW_NUMBER).

If watch this in the SQL Profiler you will see that exactly two queries are executed and at no point it will try to retrieve the full table.

---

Be careful when you are using the debugger, because if you step after the first statement and try to look at the contents of `query` that will execute the SQL query.  Maybe that is the source of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks! Your note about the debugger is very helpful - debugging `query` was what prompted me to ask this question. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Execute the query
var query = db.Entity.Where(e => e.Something == something);
```

For your information, **nothing is called** after the first statement.

```
// Get the total num records
var total = query.Count();
```

This count query will be translated to SQL, and it'll make a call to database.
This call will not get all records, because the generated SQL is something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Entity where Something LIKE 'something'
```

For the last query, **it doesn't get all the records neither**. The query will be translated into SQL, and the paging run in the database.

Maybe you'll find this question useful: [efficient way to implement paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548475/efficient-way-to-implement-paging)

Comment: Thanks! +1. If I could give out 2 checkmarks, I would, but Equiso was slightly more helpful with his note about the debugger. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe Entity Framework might structure the SQL query with the appropriate conditions based on the linq statements. (e.g. using ROWNUMBER() OVER ...).

I could be wrong on that, however. I'd run SQL profiler and see what the generated query looks like.