# Lib for LIMIT statement in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

Is there some lib or function i can use to take my basic sql statement and transform the limit statement to a sql server compatible statement?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You mean making SQL Server understand `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`?

Comment: Dan: I need the offset. ex: LIMIT offset, amount. I can easily browse a page by doing LIMIT pageNumber*amount, amount. How do i do that with sqlserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent of MySQL's LIMIT function is the TOP function. So

```
Select..
From Table
LIMIT 10
```

In SQL Server this would be:

```
Select TOP 10 ...
From Table
Order By ...
```

**ADDITION**

Per your comments, you are asking about mimicking the offset parameter on LIMIT. You can do that with a CTE in SQL Server 2005+:

```
With NumberedItems As
    (
    Select ...
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order By ... ) As Num
    From Table
    )
Select ...
From NumberedItems
Where Num Between 5 And 20
```

Comment: I need the offset to. limit 5, 15 would be like top 20 ignoring first 5. -edit- so its not exactly as simple as a find/replace when there are two params.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - If you show us the query that you would run in MySQL that you want to run in SQL Server, we can show you how to write the equivalent.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - Ah, you want to know about the offset parameter which is a different kettle of fish. I've updated my post to illustrate how you can achieve that using a CTE (and assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+). There is no 1:1 equivalent function to the LIMIT with an offset parameter in SQL Server.

Comment: @KM - Granted, although if you are going to use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER, you might as well go all the way.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're wanting to use `LIMIT`'s offset functionality for pagination, in which case the SO question
["What is the best way to paginate results in MS SQLServer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-ms-sqlserver) has a very good accepted answer.

Comment: Ok thats good but i am generating the SQL. The existing code outputs a limit which is easily understood. I need something to convert the sql.