# Paging for table data in MVC 3 application with ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are using MVC 3 with ADO.NET. We have to display huge amount of records in screen in a grid. Currently we are using simple html table for the same. We would like to implement paging for the records. 
All the examples on Net are showing the paging using Entity framework. Any suggestions how to achieve the same using classical ADO.NET? No third party controls.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109290/29407) which illustrates an efficient way to perform paging directly in SQL Server using plain ADO.NET. You could also take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6936/Paging-of-Large-Resultsets-in-ASP-NET). You will of course encapsulate this in a repository method to which you will pass the current page number and the number of records that you wish per page. Then on the UI layer you could use the [WebGrid helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) which might simplify the task of presenting the data to the user.