# c# Entity Framework paginated select?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to implement pagination using Entity Framework.

What I have:

- I have the number of records I need to select (Let's say 10)
- I have the index of the record I want to start from (Page 2 = 2*10 = record 20)

> How can I directly select 10 records without selecting them all and then
>   use `.skip` and `.take`?

Comment: please show your code so far that you have tried

Comment: What is the issue with `.Skip` and `.Take`? It's usually how it's done.

Comment: Do not even know if is this possible, the only doc I found from microsoft is for MVC with some nuget packages, and there is no info on SO @HamzaHaider

Comment: Please See This Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145815/c-sharp-entity-framework-pagination

Comment: @Longoon12000 using `skip` and `take` implies to select every record on the table before using them, right? If I have thousands of records wouldn't that be too slow?

Comment: @teraxxx: *"wouldn't that be too slow?"* - Would it?  Why assume that without testing it?  If you're truly curious about the SQL being generated by these expressions then you can profile the database and capture the query that's executed.  You can copy that query into your SQL tools, profile its execution plan, etc.  It sounds like you're not trying to solve a problem you've encountered, but instead trying to solve a problem you've imagined.

Comment: As far as I understand it, as long as you don't to `.ToList` (fetch all) before the `.Skip` and `.Take` it will use whatever means possible (eg. SQL or enumerator magic) to do it as fast as possible. At least that's how I've always done it and it has worked so far without any bad performance impacts.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that info. Thanks a lot! @Longoon12000

Comment: We can just look at the source code of [Skip](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,83ec6a20321060a1) and [Take](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceb7d3d4f0a39720). To understand how it works. Skip will use `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext` . Then Take will iterate and return just what needed. And leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework is quite clever as to how it translates LINQ queries to query statements, as in it optimizes the query for you.

Doing

```cs
context.Employess.Where(x => x.Age >= 18).Skip(20).Take(10);
```

Will not load all employees into memory, filter them by age, skip 20 and then return 10. It will create an SQL query that only returns the 10 employees you actually want. That LINQ query will be translated to something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, age, col3, col4...
  FROM employees
  WHERE age >= 18
  ORDER BY id
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

That SQL Query will only return 10 rows, after skipping 20. Also note that it will only execute the query once you act on the Enumerable, this is because LINQ uses [Deferred Execution](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution)

**Edit:** The SQL statement I supplied will only work on SQL Server 2012 und upwards, as `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` were only introduced then

Answer (score 0):

You should first `Skip` from the whole collection and after that `Take`. Below is the sample code -

```
var objList = (from c in dbcontext.Employees                         
                    orderby c.DepartmentId select c)
                    .Skip(skipQuantity).Take(numberofRecords);
```