# Getting Count and Rows in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the total table `count` and `rows` in same query. something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(1),*
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ALL
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always try something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (),
    (list of your other columns here)
FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
```

The `OVER()` clause will give you a count of all rows right in your query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
SELECT (select count(*) from table), b.*
  FROM table b;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

1) `select column1,coulmn2,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) as RowCnt from #Table;`

2)Using the cross join method:

```
SELECT a.*, b.numRows
      FROM TABLE a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows
              FROM TABLE) b
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this one too and marc_c answer will be more better than this

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) from tbl) AS Total,*
FROM tbl
```