# want to do sql pagination for gridview in vb.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi Actually I want to do sql pagination in sql server 2008 for a single table gridview which has nearly 50 rows, please help me to create sp for that pagination

Comment: look what google says if you search for 'sql'-pagination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Set the `EnablePaging` property of the gridview.

Comment: gridview pagination is already there i need to do sql pagination\