# Place XML Child nodes under multiple parent nodes of the same element

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt

I have a database query that pulls multiple candidates under one race and places them into an XML file. My problem I have ran into, is that some races have more than 2 candidates. My template for the XML data can only take 2 candidates at a time. It is an Election Ticker. So far, I have the query setup so it pulls at least 4 candidates. Naturally, if a race has less than 4 candidates, it omits the NULL data and still outputs the 2 candidates for that race. I have now even ran into races that my have 18+ candidates. This is turning into quite a chore. here is my query:

```
select  rc.[race number] AS RaceNumber,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then title1 end) as title1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [precinct percent] end) as PrecintPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [candidate num] end) as Winner,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then party end) as WinningParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then leader end) as Winner1,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as WinnerSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then [leader percent] end) as WinnerPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [candidate num] end) as Loser,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then party end) as LosingParty,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then leader2 end) as Loser2,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then [leader2 percent] end) as LoserPercent,
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as LoserSelected,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then [candidate num] end) as Winner3,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then Votes end) as Winner3Votes,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then party end) as Winner3Party,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then [first name]+[last name]end) as Winner3, 
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as Winner3Selected,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then [candidate num] end) as Loser4,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then Votes end) as Loser4Votes,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then party end) as Loser4Party,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then [first name]+ [last name]end) as Loser4,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then CAST(winner AS tinyint) end) as Loser4Selected


from 
(
select  
        r.title1,
        r.[precinct percent],
        rc.[race number],
        rc.[candidate num],
        rc.[Votes],
        rc.[winner],
        c.[party],
        r.[leader],
        r.[leader percent],
        r.[leader2],
        r.[leader2 percent],
        c.[first name],
        c.[last name],


            row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
    from    dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
    inner join dbo.[CANDIDATE] c    on  rc.[candidate num]  = c.[candidate number]
    inner join dbo.[RACE] r
     on rc.[race number] = r.[race number] 

) rc
group by rc.[race number]
FOR XML PATH ('ELECTION'), ROOT('root')
```

Again, this outputs at least 4 candidates, if there are 4. Here is a snippet from the xml document:

```
<root>
  <ELECTION>
    <RaceNumber>101</RaceNumber>
    <title1>President</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5083</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>999877</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>D</WinningParty>
    <Winner1>Barack Obama</Winner1>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <WinnerPercent>53</WinnerPercent>
    <Loser>5077</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>888888</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>R</LosingParty>
    <Loser2>Mitt Romney</Loser2>
    <LoserPercent>47</LoserPercent>
    <LoserSelected>0</LoserSelected>
  </ELECTION>
  <ELECTION>
    <RaceNumber>102</RaceNumber>
    <title1>U.S. Congress Dist. 1</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5085</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>216879</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>D</WinningParty>
    <Winner1>Bruce Braley</Winner1>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <WinnerPercent>57</WinnerPercent>
    <Loser>5086</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>159657</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>R</LosingParty>
    <Loser2>Ben Lange</Loser2>
    <LoserPercent>42</LoserPercent>
    <LoserSelected>0</LoserSelected>
  </ELECTION>
  <ELECTION>
    <RaceNumber>133</RaceNumber>
    <title1>DesMoines County Board of Supervisors</title1>
    <PrecintPercent>100</PrecintPercent>
    <Winner>5154</Winner>
    <WinningVotes>11629</WinningVotes>
    <WinningParty>D</WinningParty>
    <Winner1>Bob  Beck</Winner1>
    <WinnerSelected>1</WinnerSelected>
    <WinnerPercent>34</WinnerPercent>
    <Loser>5155</Loser>
    <LosingVotes>11323</LosingVotes>
    <LosingParty>D</LosingParty>
    <Loser2>Jim Cary</Loser2>
    <LoserPercent>33</LoserPercent>
    <LoserSelected>1</LoserSelected>
    <Winner3>5156</Winner3>
    <Winner3Votes>7018</Winner3Votes>
    <Winner3Party>R</Winner3Party>
    <Winner3>DarwinBunger</Winner3>
    <Winner3Selected>0</Winner3Selected>
    <Loser4>5157</Loser4>
    <Loser4Votes>4415</Loser4Votes>
    <Loser4Party>R</Loser4Party>
    <Loser4>JamesSeaberg</Loser4>
    <Loser4Selected>0</Loser4Selected>
  </ELECTION>
```

If you notice,  133, has 4 candidates in it. What I am trying to do is get  133 to show the first 2 candidates, then create a duplicate node with the remaining candidates names/votes etc in it.

Here is the XSL file I am parsing my election XML data into the ticker with:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<tickerfeed version="2.4">


 <!-- START ELECTION CAROUSEL -->

  <playlist type="flipping_carousel" name="ELECTION2" target="carousel">
    <defaults>
      <outputchannels>
        <active>ABC</active>
        <active>MYNTV</active>
      </outputchannels>
      <gui-color>#CCFF99</gui-color>
    </defaults>

    <xsl:for-each select="root/ELECTION">
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <template>ELECTION_RESULTS</template>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">50</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="title1" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">51</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="PrecinctPercent" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">52</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="WinnerSelected" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">53</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="Winner1" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">54</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="WinnerPercent" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">55</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="WinningVotes" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">56</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="LoserSelected" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">57</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="Loser2" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">58</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="LoserPercent" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">59</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="LosingVotes" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">60</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="WinningParty" />
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="field">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">61</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="LosingParty" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</playlist>



 <!-- END ELECTION CAROUSEL -->
```

I suppose my question is, can this be accomplished?

Should I do the operation in the XSL file or the SQL Query?

My current Query is the only way I have been able to get multiple canadidates to output. I would just like to figure out how to duplicate the Race Number, especially the RACETITLE  with the remaining candidates, since my ticker template can only show 2 candidates at a time.

If someone could tell me yes or no, that would be ideal, but I have to get it figured out one way or another. Thanks everyone for your help.

EDIT**

I just want races that have more than 2 candidates to split into their own nodes, rather than outputting into one single node, with all 4 candidates information, such as RACE 133, I would like to have 2 -RACE 133 nodes, the first one with the first set of candidates and the second node with the second set of candidates. Assuming that the race has 4 candidates. I don't know...I am getting to a point where I feel this is not even possible.

I really am trying to figure out if I should focus more on the query or try to get the desired output using a more complex XSL file. Pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Suggestion: Boil this down to it simplest terms, stripping away all the extra stuff that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem. That is, replace your real snippets with a bare bones set of sample data, sql, xslt, and desired out put. It'll be far easier for us to help at that point.

Comment: @KarlKieninger I will try to do this. my SQL returns 298 Rows of data.

Comment: I have no clue how to better ask the question. I suppose I ought to tell myself, "Sorry man".

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to fight this - as much as possible - on a single front (either SQL or XSLT). If you decide to go with XSLT (fully or partially), do NOT number your elements, e.g. `<Winner1>`, `<Winner2>`, etc. XSLT is smart enough to count elements of the same name and, if necessary, pick only the first N out of them, or group them into equal-sized groups.

Comment: BTW, in your last race (133) you have designated the candidate with 11,323 votes as `<Loser>` while the next candidate with 7,018 votes is `<Winner3>`. That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

What I was getting at in my comment is that it would be easier to work with if instead of using your real data you created a sample set with  minimal rows and only a couple fields. Get completely away from candidates and elections and just work with some dummy data that shows the same scenario.

I'll try to offer some advice, because I believe I understand what you are asking.

> I suppose my question is, can this be accomplished?

Yes, I think it can.

> Should I do the operation in the XSL file or the SQL Query?

I think you can do this either way, but my XSL isn't strong enough tonight to come up with the how.

So focusing on the SQL, I think you can split your query into two and then union the results before doing the FOR XML. That way the quad will be split into pairs before hitting XML. Getting seqnums 1 and 2 for the first part and 3 and 4 for the second.

You borrow from the [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server) techniques here to get the pairs of seqnums

What version of MSSQL, btw?

Comment: MSSQL 2008. That is a great idea. I will see what I can come up with trying to divide it in the SQL. I asked another question, trying to sum it up with less info, but I will try to split them before the XML like you suggested. Thanks for the confidence. I am still exploring modifying the XML with VB post outputting the file. err... I can make it about as complicated as I can. ha. Thanks Again and will let you know what I come up with. I will need to figure out how to split the query correctly first. Thanks!