# MySQL - how to order multiple columns with pagination efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, sql-order-by, limit

Say I have these four tables:

```
BRANCH (BRANCH_ID, CITY_ID, OWNER_ID, SPECIALTY_ID, INAUGURATION_DATE)
CITY (CITY_ID, NAME)
OWNER (ONWER_ID, NAME)
SPECIALTY (SPECIALTY_ID, NAME)
```

I have a PrimeFaces datatable where I will show all branches using pagination of 50 (`LIMIT X, 50`). Today `BRANCH` has like 10000 rows. I'll join `BRANCH` with the other 3 tables because I want to show their names.

I want to fetch the results with the following default sort:

`ORDER BY INAUGURATION_DATE ASC, C.NAME ASC, O.NAME ASC, S.NAME ASC`

Now, the user can choose to click in the header of any of these columns in my datatable, and I will query the database again making the sort he asked as the priority one. For instance, if he chose to order first by specialty name, descending, I'll do:

`ORDER BY S.NAME DESC, INAUGURATION_DATE ASC, C.NAME ASC, O.NAME ASC`

Now my question: how can I query the database with this dynamic sort always using the 4 columns, **efficiently**? A lot of users can be viewing this datatable in my site at the same time (like 1000 users), so using the `ORDER BY` in the SQL is **very slow**. I'm doing the ordering in Java, but then I cannot do the pagination correctly. How can I make this efficiently in SQL? Is creating indexes for these columns enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

10000 rows is quite small, so mysql should be able to handle that very fast. Assuming you have proper indexes on the City, Owner, and Speciality class (which will be the case if you declare primary keys) this query should return quickly.  Also be sure to use LIMIT 50 in your query.  However if the number of rows becomes large (like a million or even much more. You should just time the query  to find out where it begins to slow down) then you individual indexes on City_ID, Owner_ID, Speciality_id, or inauguration_date will not help. To take advantage of the sort, assuming that your are just doing a join and there are no where clauses then you the index will need to be on all columns in the order you wish to sort.  So you will need quite a few indexes to cover all the cases.  If performance becomes an issue, you may want to consider whether the application needs all those options. Perhaps you could  offer the user to change  the sort of just any one column. In that case individual indexes will help.  Also when the number of rows gets large, the performance bottleneck may not be sorting but rather how you are performing the pagination.  I like the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609938/4350148.

One last point. Mysql caches queries by default. So if the tables are not changing then the queries should return without even having to do the sorting.