# php pagination, using sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, pagination

so, i am newbie in php development, i want to create a pagination with php pdo and sql server, 
first page works great, but other pages from pagination not work
(sorry for my english, i am from brazil)

follows my code

```
<?php

require 'conn.php';
$pdo = dbConnect();

$limite = 10;

$pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? (int)$_GET['pg'] : 1;

$inicio = ($pg * $limite) - $limite;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID_USUARIO) as row FROM tbl_usuario) a WHERE row between ".$inicio." and ".$limite.""; 

try {

        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        } catch (PDOexception $error_sql){

                echo 'Erro ao retornar os Dados.'.$error_sql->getMessage();
}

while($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>

                <?php 
                echo $linha['NOME'].'</br>'; 

                ?> 
<?php }


$sql_Total = 'SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM tbl_usuario';

try {
        $query_Total = $pdo->prepare($sql_Total);
        $query_Total->execute();
        $query_result = $query_Total->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query_count =  $query_Total->rowCount(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        $qtdPag = ceil($query_count/$limite);

        } catch (PDOexception $error_Total){

                echo 'Erro ao retornar os Dados. '.$error_Total->getMessage();

        }


        echo "<div class='relax h30'></div>";
        echo '<a href="teste?pg=1">PRIMEIRA PÁGINA</a>&nbsp;';
        echo '<ul id="paginacao">';
    echo '<li><a class="anterior" href="teste?pg=1">Anterior</a></li>';

        if($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag){

                for($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++){

                        if($i == $pg){

                                echo "<li><a class='ativo'>".$i."</a></li>";

                        } else {

                                echo "<li><a href='teste?pg=$i'>".$i."</a></li>";

                        }

                }

        }

        echo "<li><a class='proxima' href='teste?pg=$qtdPag'>Próxima</a></li>";

?>
```

Comment: So we should guess ourselves how it `not work`? Or maybe you have some examples?

Comment: I can't see any SQL injection here, but since you are using PDO, using parameter binding would be a very good idea, and very easy.

Comment: @u_mulder i like know how i can pagination works

Comment: Break the problem down into smaller problems. For page 1, 2, 3 etc, what values do you have for `$inicio`? Then work out what query you would get, and run that directly in your database console. Are the results as you would expect?

Comment: There are a good number of questions to the right `----->` that refer to "Pagination... SQL Server". I expect you will find those helpful? [This one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for rows between $inicio and $limite. On page 1 that means we would be getting rows 0 to 10, which is correct. Page 2 however would be rows 10 to 10, which is none.

You should create a new variable to determine the number of the last row, example:

```
$lastRow = $inicio + $limite;
```

And then just:

```
WHERE row between ".$inicio." and ".$lastRow.";
```

Comment: the code repeat the last row, but thank you this would be useful

Comment: You do realise that the post you marked as the answer is pretty much the exact same thing as I said right?

Comment: but two answers seems right. i don't know what do i new in this site, sorry

Comment: Getting marked as the answer does not really bother me, it's just that your comment made it seem like this was not your solution.