# selecting the next set of top 30 records

Tags: sql-server

This is my query:

```
SELECT Top 30 *  
FROM  (SELECT *,  Row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY EntityPicURL 
                                     ORDER BY FavoriteCount desc) AS RN
       FROM   TweetEntity   
       WHERE HashTag LIKE '%%23RIPOlgaSyahputra%') A
WHERE  RN = 1 
ORDER BY FavoriteCount desc , LastModifieddateTime desc
```

This will select the first 30 unique records of the column `entitypicURl`. Now that I want to select the next 30 records (31-60).

This is a sort of a query i used earlier but this returned many duplicate entries of `entitypicURL`.

```
select * 
from (select *, row_no = row_number() over (order by FavoriteCount desc,
                                                     LastModifiedDateTime desc)
      from TweetEntity 
      where HashTag like '%%23RIPOlgaSyahputra%') e 
where e.row_no > 30 and e.row_no <=60
```

Now i want to combine the value of first query and include `e.row_no>30 and e.row_no<60` from the second query.

It is not a duplicate. My confusion is just combining two queries because both has got row_numbers.

Comment: which version of sql server you are using

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: It is not a duplicate. My confusion is just combining two queries because both has got row_numbers

Comment: Please post the results you are getting from the query you tried, and how they are different from the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `CTE`s like this:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
   SELECT *,  
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityPicURL
                            ORDER BY FavoriteCount desc) AS RN
   FROM   TweetEntity   
   WHERE HashTag like '%%23RIPOlgaSyahputra%'
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER FavoriteCount DESC, 
                                   LastModifiedDateTime DESC) AS row_no    
   FROM CTE1
   WHERE RN = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2 
WHERE row_no > 30 and row_no <=60
```

`CTE2` will apply `ROW_NUMBER` on the *filtered by `RN = 1`* result set of `CTE1`.

Comment: Fantastic. This is what I was looking for. A query with in a query. It worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `OFFSET` to fetch records like this

you can select 30 records from below query

```
Select * FROM   TweetEntity
ORDER BY FavoriteCount  desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY
```

you can select next 30 records from below query

```
 Select * FROM   TweetEntity
ORDER BY FavoriteCount  desc OFFSET 30  ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY
```

**Note:** `OFFSET` Will work on **Sql server 2012+**

**Limitations in Using OFFSET-FETCH**

- ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause.
- OFFSET clause is mandatory with FETCH. You can never use, ORDER BY …
  FETCH.
- TOP cannot be combined with OFFSET and FETCH in the same query
  expression.
- The OFFSET/FETCH rowcount expression can be any arithmetic, constant,
  or  parameter expression that will return an integer value. The
  rowcount expression does not support scalar sub-queries.

Comment: If you look at my second query It has got the pagination. My question is however getting the first query into pagination as I am not able to merge two row_numbers properly

Comment: @Venkat i suggest you a way for pagination