# Using SQL That Return Varied Columns with Out Of Memory asp mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm working on a generic search from an object and his relation objects. I execute a SQL query and display the data dynamically on a grid. The problem that I faced is that my query returns varied Columns (more then 18) and so much data (1474656 records) and when I return the data to display them in the grid an Out Of MemoryException occured. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why on earth you are loading 1474656 rows into grid???

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri i have a very large data to display ,i'm working on generic search to display an object by filtering it with all its proprotes and all related objects

Comment: That's what paging is for...

Comment: What would a user even *do* with 14,746,56  rows of data? Take a book from the library, don't walk around with the building

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: You'll have to dynamically add an order by and add the paging clause (depending on your version of SQL Server.) If you need to know the total number of pages you'll need to execute the query again, aggregating the count but omitting the paging.

Answer (score 0):

Your grid needs to either implement a paging solution (fairly easy) or you need to load rows on demand as the user scrolls down (could be a little bit more difficult).  Regardless, you should only be loading a small subset of the data as needed for display on the UI.

Comment: i use a sql server 2008 which pagination must i use? please help me with a documentataion

Comment: You're a developer - implement a paging solution yourself in the application code.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged Kendo Grid, so I will assume you're using that.

Implementing paging is very easy with Kendo Grid, by setting a page size in the datasource and configuring `pageable`.

**Example**

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")'
        },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 550,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 200
    }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title"
    }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
    }, {
        field: "Country",
        width: 150
    }]
});
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult MyAction([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request) {
    var result = BL.GetYourData();
    return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

`ToDataSourceResult` will apply your paging, so only 20 records will be returned to the client. If your data access is set up properly your SQL Server will also only return 20 records.