# How to select 'x' products from 'n' products

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database-performance, usability

I have 20000 products in DB. Want to show 20 on load and rest others onclick button. I dont want to load all the 20000 initially. Please advise

Comment: Why don't you use `Top` for selecting top 20 records?

Comment: Using `SqlCommand`, `Entity Framework`?

Comment: Use `LIMIT` clause in SQL Query. `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 20` at the time loading. Then on the button click event, `SELECT * FROM TABLE1`.

Comment: If this is Oracle SQL remember to use `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROWNUM < 20` or similar

Comment: FYI it's called pagination http://stackoverflow.com/q/109232/800613

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM yourTable;
```

This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) gives more information about `Top`

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq instead, since it does not bother about the syntax that the db expects(using LIMIT/TOP in select query).

```
var query=(from c in context.yourTable
           select c).Take(20).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from (
Select row_number() Over(Order by Columnname) rw,* from Tablename ) t where t.rw between 1 and 20