# Pagination in SQL Server 2012 stored procedure with top distinct(x) records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create stored procedure with pagination along with top 100 against a subset of a table. For example in a table(ex:employee table) with more than 3,000,000 records, I want to take the top 100,000 records and do the pagination. I'm able to do the pagination using below script, but I want to take the top 100,000 records and do the pagination.

```
DECLARE @currentPageNo int,@takeData int
SET @currentPageNo =1
SET @takeData = 10

SELECT DISTINCT emp.empid,emp.name,s.Salary,
FROM Employee emp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN salary S ON emp.empid=S.empid
where emp.empid=12
ORDER BY emp.empid desc
OFFSET (@currentPageNo - 1) *   @takeData  ROWS
 FETCH NEXT   @takeData  ROWS ONLY
```

I need some suggestions on how this can be achieved. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Not everyone understands the Indian(?) numbering system so you should edit your question and replace `lack` and `crore` with either proper English terms or numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: This question does not make a lot of sense. What is top lack?

Comment: @JulienVavasseur it is lakh or lak. It is part of the Indian numbering system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: I first try to read and understand the question as it has been politely replied to Tab Alleman. Jpw suggested to edit the question with proper explanation or terms understandable by everyone. Nothing has been done. As it is, what this means is not obvious and should be properly explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform pagination properly you will need to ensure the order of the result set and assign row numbers, for this you can use ROWNUMBER() OVER()

You will also need to know the total count of the entire result set. This will tell you how many total pages you have.  You can do this in a secondary query or add another column for Total Rows using COUNT() OVER()

Here's an example using your variables:

```
DECLARE @currentPageNo int,@takeData int
SET @currentPageNo =0
SET @takeData = 10  

  SELECT TOP(@currentPageNo) * FROM
    (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ColumnName]) RowNumber, *
                FROM (

                    SELECT DISTINCT emp.empid,emp.name,s.Salary,COUNT(emp.empid) OVER() TotalRows
                    FROM Employee emp 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN salary S ON emp.empid=S.empid
                    where emp.empid=12
                ) Q1        
    ) Q2
    WHERE ( @takeData<>0 AND RowNumber BETWEEN ((@currentPageNo * @takeData) + 1) AND ((@currentPageNo +1) * @takeData))
```