# SQL Server: pagination of "distinct" records

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables and columns as below

```
resource: id, location.
subject: id, name
resource_subject: resource_id, subject_id
```

The relationship between "resource" and "subject" is many-to-many. Here is the query I have:

```
select r.* from resource r 
inner join resource_subject subject on r.id = subject.resource_id 
where (subject.subject_id= 2 or subject.subject_id= 4)
```

Queries as the above may produce duplicate records because one resource may belong to more than one subject. So, to remove the duplicates, I use **distinct** as the following:

```
select distinct r.* from resource r 
inner join resource_subject subject on r.id = subject.resource_id 
where (subject.subject_id= 2 or subject.subject_id= 4)
```

Now I want to do pagination of unique records. I read this SO post,

[What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

I am interested in using **ROW_NUMBER()**. However, using ROW_NUMBER() would make duplicate records unique:

```
select distinct ROW_NUMBER() over( order by r.id asc) AS rownum, r.* from resource r 
inner join resource_subject subject on r.id = subject.resource_id 
where (subject.subject_id= 2 or subject.subject_id= 4)
```

How can I do ROW_NUMBER() over records after "distinct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the `row_number` in Outer Query

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum, 
                * 
         FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
                 FROM   resource r 
                        INNER JOIN resource_subject subject 
                                ON r.id = subject.resource_id 
                 WHERE  subject.subject_id IN ( 2, 4 )) A) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rownum >= 1 
       AND rownum <= 10
```

But if you are using `Sql Server 2012+` then use `OFFSET` for pagination which will be faster than `Row_number`

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.* 
FROM   resource r 
       INNER JOIN resource_subject subject 
               ON r.id = subject.resource_id 
WHERE  subject.subject_id IN ( 2, 4 ) 
ORDER  BY r.id 
offset 1 rows FETCH next 10 rows only;
```

Comment: Hello VR46, thanks for your working code. And thanks for formatting the query!

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `DENSE_RANK()` instead

[`ROW_NUMBER()` is to `SELECT` what `DENSE_RANK()` is to `SELECT DISTINCT`](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/). The below application of `DENSE_RANK()` will produce row numbers as if they were produced *after* applying `DISTINCT`.

```sql
select distinct DENSE_RANK() over( order by r.id asc) AS rownum, r.* from resource r 
inner join resource_subject subject on r.id = subject.resource_id 
where (subject.subject_id= 2 or subject.subject_id= 4)
```

#### How does it work?

This is best explained by example, also from the [linked article](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/)

```sql
SELECT
  v, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY v),
  RANK()       OVER(ORDER BY v),
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY v)
FROM (
  VALUES('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),
        ('c'),('c'),('d'),('e')
) t(v);
```

The above yields:

```
| V | ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK |
|---|------------|------|------------|
| a |          1 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          2 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          3 |    1 |          1 |
| b |          4 |    4 |          2 |
| c |          5 |    5 |          3 |
| c |          6 |    5 |          3 |
| d |          7 |    7 |          4 |
| e |          8 |    8 |          5 |
```