# Best choce to pull data with pagination in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

one way is we can use row_number function as follows to pull data from db.

```
select * from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SalesOrderDate desc) as rn, *
    from sales.salesorderheader
) as x
where rn BETWEEN ( ((@Index - 1) * @PageSize )+ 1) AND @Index * @PageSize
```

### another way is

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT EmpID FROM dbo.Emp
    ORDER BY EmpID
    OFFSET  @PageSize * (@Index - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT e.columns
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.Emp AS e
ON x.EmpID = e.EmpID
ORDER BY ...;
```

tell me which one is good and when to use which one? thanks

Comment: Second approach at any case, though the queries look different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Additional help/support for pagination was added in 2012.

Comment: It depends what indexes you have and what page number you are requesting.

Comment: In the possible duplicate link, I prefer [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609938/243373).

Comment: Best in what way? Also, wouldn't it be easier for you just to test it, instead of asking from random persons in the internet?