# How do I load a list using Limit and load more rows after last loaded row using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Queue in Java which is populated form SQL with a Limit of 10, when the queue is empty I want to load the 10 next row in the table. How is this possible?. Currently I only get the same 10 rows every time the queue is empty.

Comment: Would you like sharing table structure or any info about primary key

Comment: its just one table with a single PK. I just want to load 10 by 10 rows while discarding the ones that already has been showed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Add one column(if you don't have in table) as sequence(1,2,3,...) and every time you pull record remember the last record's sequence and next time start by that.
For example: First ten records

```
select * from table where sequence <11
```

For another 10 records

```
select * from table where sequence >10 and sequence <21
```

If your pk is string, just remember the last value of your primary key

For example: First ten records

```
select * from table limit 10;
```

for next 10 records, say last value of pk from previous fetch was "abc"

```
select * from table where pk>"abc" limit 10
```