# Mysql return multiple unique rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, organization

How does any app that returns a list from a database return unique rows when you click page 2,3...etc of the results? Say I have an app that communicates with a node-js server which queries a mysql db. How can I ensure efficiency when querying the database for more 'pages(list of rows) of data? How can I avoid SELECT * .
This isn't specifically a mysql question just an organizational one.

Comment: Look into the `LIMIT` sql keyword.

Comment: I know I can limit the results, but how can I ensure that I'm returning unique rows each time I query for a new page?

Comment: You can't. What if there are new records between the first and second requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you mean pagination.
It's like words on pages in a book.
Say you can place only `250` words on one "page".
The whole "book" contains `26788` words that is... `ceiling of 26788/250 = 108` "pages".

If that is what you mean, there are already [some good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109290/4280359) on StackOverflow.