# Implementation of pagination in coldfusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, coldfusion

We are trying to implement pagination in coldfusion.So that I need to make changes in sql query to fetch only a perticular number of data and when clicking on next button, next set of data should be queried.

```
  SELECT    History.*,User.FirstName,User.LastName
  FROM History 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN User ON History.UserID = User.UserID
  WHERE History.UserID = <CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#UserID#" CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER">   
  AND Type IS NOT NULL
  AND SubType IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY #OrderBy# #sort#
```

Can anyone help me to do the same with above given query.

example query :

```
   SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SearchID) AS NUMBER, 
                * FROM search_history 
                WHERE UserID=111
                AND Date >= #DateVal#     
           ) AS TBL
   WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN ((#pageNum# - 1) * #MaxRows# + 1) AND (#pageNum# * #MaxRows#)
   ORDER BY #OrderBy# #sort#
```

Comment: Watch out for the SQL Injection in your ORDER BY.  What versions of ColdFusion and SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is an issue with SQL Server and not ColdFusion. You're just generating the query inline with ColdFusion. It would be better if you create this query as a stored procedure, which by nature would perform better than an inline query.

Second, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server) is the basis for the example I'm posting. SQL Server famously has not supported `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, which makes paging dead simple. These have been in MySQL and postgreSql forever.

Third, as of SQL Server 2012, there is now support for `OFFSET` and `FETCH` (essentially `LIMIT`). [Here is a good example](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) of how that works.

This example uses SQL `@parameters`. Ideally you would declare these in a stored procedure, but you can declare and set them in your inline query. Just make sure to use [cfqueryparam](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) to protect against [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. 
`SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        h.column1
        , h.column2
        , u.FirstName
        , u.LastName
        , SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY @ORDER_BY @SORT_ORDER ) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        dbo.History h
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.User u ON h.UserID = u.UserID
    WHERE 
        h.UserID = @USER_ID
        AND 
        h.Type IS NOT NULL
        AND 
        h.SubType IS NOT NULL 
) AS HistorySearch
WHERE 
    RowNum >= @ROW_START
    AND
    RowNum < @ROW_END
ORDER BY 
    RowNum`

You'll want to calculate the values of `ROW_START` and `ROW_END` based on the page number and a page size variable.

Finally, don't use `SELECT *` in your main select query. It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you are returning you can do your query normally and do pagination on the output with cold fusion. And if you can avoid using * in the query that is a good idea.

```
<cfparam name="StartAt" default="1">
<cfparam name="MaxRows" default="100">

<cfoutput name="QueryName" startrow="#StartAt#" maxrows="#maxRows#" >
```

The variables MaxRows and StartAt would be set in your form, and passed when the user clicks Next or previous.

If you have a very large result set then limiting the data returned would be a better idea as you have put forward.

Comment: query result is very large and crashing the application in between. so that only we started thinking about alternative.