# Running a large query tot he BigQuery API with python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am writing a python function that runs a query against BigQuery tables and writes the result out to another table, here is my function with a small query:

```
def generate_user_pit(days_ago):
    ### Generate a user facts table for x days ago and save it into BigQuery
    days_ago = days_ago
    query = """
    SELECT
    Date,
    sum(totals.visits)
    FROM
      `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
    WHERE
      parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
        _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL @days_ago day)
      AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL @days_ago day)
    GROUP BY Date
    """
    query_params = [
    bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('days_ago', 'INT64', days_ago),
    ]

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'


    print("Generating dataframe...")
    df = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()

    date = df['Date'].max()
    table_name = "data_"
    complete_table_name = table_name + date

    dataset_ref = client.dataset('test')
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(complete_table_name)

    print("Writing", complete_table_name, "to BigQuery...")
    client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref).result()

    print("Done!")
```

This works as expected, but when I run it with my actual query, which is much more memory intensive, I am hitting `Memory Error`.

Is there anything I can do to improve this function and make it more efficient? For example, I don't *need* the query written to a dataframe, this is just the way I've been able to get it to function now.

Here is my query that is returning that is maxing out memory:

```
WITH Q1 AS(
    SELECT
      customDimension.value AS UserID,
      # Visits from this individual
      COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING))) AS visits,
      # Orders from this individual
      COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS orders,
      # COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId)/COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId) AS frequency,
      # Conversion rate of the individual
      SAFE_DIVIDE(COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId),
        COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)))) AS conversion_rate,

       # first visit date
      MIN(Date) AS first_visit_date,

      # last visit date
      MAX(DATE) AS last_visit_date

    FROM
      `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST (hits) AS hits
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
    WHERE
      parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
        _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 999 day)
      AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL @days_ago day)
      AND customDimension.index = 2
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "true"
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "false"
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "undefined"
      AND customDimension.value IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      UserID
    ),
    Q2 AS(
    SELECT
      customDimension.value AS UserID,
      IFNULL(SUM(totals.bounces),0) AS bounces,
      IFNULL(SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000,0) AS revenue

    FROM
      `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*` AS t

    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension

        WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
    DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 999 day) and
    DATE_sub(current_date(), interval @days_ago day)

      AND customDimension.index = 2
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "true"
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "false"
      AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE "undefined"
      AND customDimension.value IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      UserID
    ),
    Q3 AS(
    SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID, MAX(Date) AS last_order
    FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS t
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
    WHERE totals.transactions > 0
    AND customDimension.index = 2
    GROUP BY UserID
    ),
    Q4 AS(
    SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID, MIN(Date) AS first_order
    FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS t
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
    WHERE totals.transactions > 0
    AND customDimension.index = 2
    GROUP BY UserID
    )

    SELECT a.UserID AS UserID,
    SUM(visits) AS visits,
    IFNULL(SUM(orders),0) AS orders,
    IFNULL(MIN(conversion_rate),0) AS conversion_rate,
    IFNULL(SUM(bounces),0) AS bounces,
    IFNULL(SUM(revenue),0) AS revenue,
    IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(revenue),SUM(orders)),0) AS AOV,
    IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(revenue),SUM(visits)),0) AS rev_per_visit,
    IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(bounces),SUM(visits)),0) AS bounce_rat

    FROM Q1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN Q2 AS b
    USING (UserID)

    LEFT JOIN Q4 AS f
    USING (UserID)

    LEFT JOIN Q3 AS l
    USING (UserID)

    GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try at least those options:
 - write query results to external file an then export
 - use a query with result paging and execute in a loop
As for Python optimization, you can try, but if results are bigger than a memory in a system, you will need sooner or later try a different approach. It all depends on how the retrieved data will be used, but in your case, I think query with paging will be the best approach. Take a look at this answer about paging:
[What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)