# Possible to get total row count in SQL Server before paginating?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
select * from sales
```

This returns about a billion rows, and I need to process the data. I would like to show the progress while the data is being processed using something like the following:

```
res=conn.execute('select * from sales s1')
total_rows = ?
processed_rows = 0
step_size = 10000
while True:
    data = res.fetchmany(step_size)
    processed_rows += step_size
    print "Progress: %s / %s" % (processed_rows, total_rows)
```

Is there a way to get the total number of rows in a SQL query without running another query (or doing an operation such as `len(res.fetchall())`, which will add a lot of overhead to the above)?

**Note:** I'm not interested in paginating here (which is what should be done). This is more a question to see if it's possible to get the TOTAL ROW COUNT in a query in SQL Server BEFORE paginating/processing the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: What you need is to paginate the result. The exact answer to your question would be something like `select count(*) from sales`, but that's still going to be terribly slow

Comment: @ShioT I'm wondering if it's possible with mssql -- I'm not interested in paginating here, just seeing if it's possible to get the above. It seems like the answer is a "no".

Comment: @ShioT would doing something like the following add a lot of overhead to the query? `results=conn.execute('SELECT  i.*, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM  (select * from sales s1) i ')`

Comment: Counting the number of rows, so long as the `where` clause is well matched with an index, is usually very fast. But as always with SQL, you have to try it to see. You could try `declare @count int; select @count = count(*) from Sales; select *, @Count from Sales;` which should perform OK.