# SQL Server to return set of top 10 records

Tags: sql-server

I have table with data something like below:

```
ID        Name
1         abc
1         xyz
2         abc
2         xyz 
2         pqr
3         abc
3         xyz
3         pqr
3         mno
3         stu
3         def
```

Now I want the result to return only top 10 records whose set is fully fetched through this query.
For example I want the result for first top 10 records to be:

```
ID        Name
1         abc
1         xyz
2         abc
2         xyz
2         pqr
```

and for next top 10 result set it should be:

```
ID      Name
3       abc
3       xyz
3       pqr
3       mno
3       stu
3       def
```

Comment: Returning the top 10 result only needs a `SELECT TOP 10` clause. What you describe seems to be *paging* though. There are a lot of similar questions and answers already, that show how to use `OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT`

Comment: What should happen if a single set contains more than 10 rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: They're looking for paging but with an unusual subrequirement - results per page isn't a set number.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my question is not about pagination, please check question again, I was talking about retrieving set of related output and if output reaches more than 10 records then it has to split WRT to ID in two different result sets

Comment: @CSharpDev that's what pagination is. Your examples show retrieving pages of 5-6 results at a time though. So what do you actually want to return, because it's not 10 records at a time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how do I split records based on count that is not fitting for first top 10 records

Comment: What does that mean? Pagination breaks results into pages of N records, eg 10. Your examples though returns 5 items in one case, 6 in the other. None of them returns 10

Comment: Are you trying to create *buckets* by ID, up to 10 items at a time? Is this why IDs `1` and `2` go together while `3` goes into a different bucket?

Comment: that is what I am not looking for, my requirement is clear that I may put top 10 in the select statement and it will return 10 records but I am breaking set for ID=3 which I do not wanted to. So instead my query should be smart enough to break first result to only 5 records and for next page it should show result of 6 records.

Comment: Your examples *contradict* your requirement. The last comment asks for something completely different from the actual question

Comment: the point you mentioned is to create buckets by ID, if you could help on how to create bucket and retrieve records based on bucket could be helpful

Comment: You can get the count per ID in each row with `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)`. You can create a running sum of those counts, and divide by 10 to get a `bucket ID`. For ID1 you'd get 2, for ID2 you'd get 5, for ID3 you'd get 11. If you divide that by 10 you can get a "BucketID" you can use for filtering

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - add 6 rows for ID 4 are that gets total 17. Divide by 10 and both ID3 and ID4 are apparently going in bucket 1, for a total of 12 rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't say that's the complete solution - I would have posted this as an answer if it was. I'm pretty sure someone has solved this in the last 20 years though, and it probably was Itzik Ben-Gan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group the data into buckets of 10, as given below:

```sql
declare @table table(id int, name varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table values
(1 ,'abc'),
(1 ,'xyz'),
(2 ,'abc'),
(2 ,'xyz'), 
(2 ,'pqr'),
(3 ,'abc'),
(3 ,'xyz'),
(3 ,'pqr'),
(3 ,'mno'),
(3 ,'stu'),
(3 ,'def');

DECLARE @Tengroups int = (SELECT COUNT(*)/10 FROM @table)
--select @Tengroups, @RemainderTenGroups
select ID, NAME, NTILE(@Tengroups) over (order by rnk) as bucket from
(SELECT ID,NAME, row_number() over(order by id) as rnk FROM @table) as t
where rnk <= @tengroups * 10
-- remaining data, which was not in groups of 10 buckets. It will be new bucket
UNION ALL
select ID, NAME, @Tengroups + 1 as bucket from
(SELECT ID,NAME, row_number() over(order by id) as rnk FROM @table) as t
where rnk > @tengroups * 10
```

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | NAME | bucket |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | abc  |      1 |
|  1 | xyz  |      1 |
|  2 | abc  |      1 |
|  2 | xyz  |      1 |
|  2 | pqr  |      1 |
|  3 | abc  |      1 |
|  3 | xyz  |      1 |
|  3 | pqr  |      1 |
|  3 | mno  |      1 |
|  3 | stu  |      1 |
|  3 | def  |      2 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up writing below query for my own question above

```
Declare @OutputTable TABLE (ID int, NAME NVarchar(50))
Declare @ID int, @total int, @tempTotal int, @count int, @minrownumb int, @outputcount int = 0
DECLARE @result table (ID int, NAME NVarchar(50), Total int, RowNumb int)
SELECT @tempTotal = 0, @count = 1

INSERT INTO @result
SELECT ID, NAME, total, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT ID, NAME, ID, count(ID) total from MyTable WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ID, NAME, ROLLUP(ID)
    ) A WHERE ID IS NULL

SELECT @minrownumb = min(RowNumb) from @result
SELECT @maxcount = CASE WHEN @maxcount > SUM(total) THEN SUM(total) ELSE @maxcount End FROM @result

WHILE @Temptotal <= @maxcount 
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID=ID, @total = Total FROM @result WHERE RowNumb = @count       
    IF (@total >=  @maxcount AND @count = @minrownumb)
        INSERT INTO @OutputTable 
            SELECT ID, NAME FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ID = @ID
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF (@total + @outputcount <= @maxcount)
            INSERT INTO @OutputTable SELECT ID, NAME  FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ID = @ID
    END

    SET @Temptotal = @Temptotal + @total
    SET @count = @count+1

    SELECT @outputcount = Count(1) FROM @OutputTable
END
```

It gave me the results in chunks of ID which fit either in one bucket of 10 records or less.