How to efficiently implement paging and total row count with Dapper in ASP.NET Core 6 for a table with millions of rows?
I am using Dapper in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, and I need to implement efficient paging for a table that contains millions of rows. Here's my current SQL query for fetching paginated results:
SELECT {fieldsString} 
FROM {joinString} 
WHERE {Condition} 
ORDER BY {orderBy} DESC 
OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageNext ROWS ONLY;

While this works for fetching a specific page, I also need to return the total row count without affecting performance, especially since the table is very large.
What is the best practice for this scenario?
Here are the options I'm considering:

Running a separate query to get the total row count using COUNT(*).
Using a COUNT(*) OVER() window function in the same query.

Which approach would be most efficient for handling millions of rows, or is there a better way to manage paging and counting in this situation?
I’d appreciate any insights or best practices for maintaining performance with large datasets.

Any reason why you didn't profile the query and simply compare execution plans to figure this out?

What SQL Dialect is that exactly?

I'll profile the query and check the execution plans I just wanted to get some input on best practices for handling large datasets before diving into that, to make sure I'm on the right path. @roten

@fildor its based on SQL Server

Then this could be for you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/109232/982149

Second option is better, but efficient paging is to do not return COUNT at all.

@fildor I previously used ROW_NUMBER() OVER (), but it was quite slow in some cases. Is this considered a best practice, or does it depend on the specific query?

@AminFarajzadeh, COUNT means find ALL rows which matches criteria. There is no so much difference how it is called. Better to take 21 rows when paging size is 20 and if 21 rows are returned, show message next 20 rows, without informing how many rows left.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv , that's a great idea! I see your point about simply taking one extra row to determine if there are more pages. This can be a practical approach for pagination. However, knowing the total count can still be useful for displaying accurate navigation controls (like page numbers) and providing a better user experience. It really depends on the specific use case and the importance of that information for the users. Thanks for your input

KEY PART is INDEXs !
U are tryign to use a dynamic query (it seems trying to find a solution for reporting) !!!
without index (u r using MSSQLServer RDBMS) may not be performant !
If you need performance pre-define parameters and define indexes for them.
For sql part any solution will work similar performance if it is written respectively!

I usually do:  var count = await source.CountAsync();  Where source is IQueryable.  (using PaginatedList nuget package)
